# How to get Immediate direct localized child component when the author modifying localized component

Tags: web8, event-system, blueprint, web8.5

**Blueprint Structure for below publications**

- C020 Test Global
- C030 Test Content Public (C020 Test Global)
- C040 Local Content Public (C020 Test Global, C030 Test Content
  Public)
- C050 Test Mobile Public (C030 Test Content Public, C040
  Local Content

Public)

- C060 Test Public Spanish (C020 Test Global, C040 Local Content
  Public)
- C062 Test Mobile Public Spanish (C060 Test Public Spanish, C050 Test Mobile Public)

**Component Created in publications**

- C020 Test Global

**Component Localized In publications**

- C040 Local Content Public - Component Localized
- C050 Test Mobile Public - Component Localized
- C060 Test Public Spanish - Component Localized
- C062 Test Mobile Public Spanish - Component Localized

**Component modified in publications**
 - C050 Test Mobile Public 
**Final Result:**

- C060 Test Public Spanish
- C062 Test Mobile Public Spanish

I want to implement the business logic to get “immediate direct localized child component, when the author modifying localized component (**C050 Test Mobile Public**) using event system.

**Looking for Suggestion and Solution for above business requirement and logic.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do definitely is use "Where used filter". It will return you all items that use your component (which includes your component). Then you can filter it via tcm id to get just local copies. 
For more information how to use GetUsingItems filter [check this blog.](http://codedweapon.com/2012/11/getting-using-and-used-items-with-tom-net/)
[image]

I think that you can also use BluePrintChainFilter with BluePrintChainDirection.Down property, where you will need to filter all localized components.

Hope this helps :)